# how to create custom push notification using asp.net webservice?

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net, web-services, push-notification

I have single app for iPhone and android.I want to implement custom push notification in my  app using asp.net webservice.

How can i do it?

Is there any sample code which manage the data with webservice?please suggest me how can i manage webservice for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please use following [code from github](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS) available for .Net push notification. You need to provide .p12 file in it and you have to set developer/production mode according to your requirement.

Comment: Is it so ? I don't find such rule anywhere mentioned on our community.

Comment: You may be interested to check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: Refer to Jeff Atwood's (who is a Moderator) Comment below Lance Robert's answer and Jeff's answer itself explains it.

Comment: Answer may be useful to other who is looking for PHP solutions which I believe so not deleted. If you Still prefer to be deleted please flag it to Moderator attention and let him decide what to do with it.

Comment: No problem. Leave it. My interest is not to get your answer deleted. But It would have been great if you could merge the answers. Nothing Personal

Answer (score 2):

**Below code is for PHP**.

There is no such Code readily available. You can do it like maintain 1 tag field in database table like 1 for iOS device and 2 for android device. I have implemented same functionality and below is code for sending push notification accordingly.

```
//This function determines which is the device and send notification accordingly.
function sendPushNotificaitonToAllUser($NotificationMsg)
{
    $sql = "select ID,DeviceToken,DeviceType from TblDeviceToken";
    $rs  = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($rs);

    if($num >= 1)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $deviceToken = $row['DeviceToken'];
            if($deviceToken!='' || $deviceToken!='NULL')
            {
                if($row['DeviceType']==1)   
                    deliverApplePushNotification($deviceToken,$NotificationMsg);
                else if($row['DeviceType']==2)  
                    sendAndroidPushNotification($deviceToken,$NotificationMsg);
            }
        }
    }     
}

//APPLE PUSH NOTIFICATION DELIVERY
function deliverApplePushNotification($deviceToken,$message)
{
    //Create context
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', PEM_FILE_NAME);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', APPLE_PEM_PASSPHRASE);

    //Establish connection
    $fp = stream_socket_client(APPLE_URL, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    /*
        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    */  

    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,   'sound' => 'default'); // Create the payload body
    $payload = json_encode($body); // Encode the payload as JSON
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;// Build the binary notification
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));// Send it to the server


    //If want to keep track of delivery can be done from here.
    /*if (!$result)
        echo '<br/>Message not delivered-->$deviceToken' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo '<br/>Message successfully delivered-->$deviceToken' . PHP_EOL;        
    */

    fclose($fp); // Close the connection to the server
}

function sendAndroidPushNotification($deviceRegistrationId,$messageText)
{   
    $authenticationID=googleAuthenticate(ANDROID_USERNAME,ANDROID_PASSWORD,ANDROID_SOURCE,ANDROID_SERVICE);
    $result= sendMessageToPhone($authenticationID,$deviceRegistrationId,ANDROID_MSGTYPE,$messageText);
}   

function googleAuthenticate($username, $password, $source="Company-AppName-Version", $service="ac2dm") 
{    
    session_start();
    if( isset($_SESSION['google_auth_id']) && $_SESSION['google_auth_id'] != null)
        return $_SESSION['google_auth_id'];

    // get an authorization token
    $ch = curl_init();
    if(!ch){
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    $post_fields = "accountType=" . urlencode('HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE')
        . "&Email=" . urlencode($username)
        . "&Passwd=" . urlencode($password)
        . "&source=" . urlencode($source)
        . "&service=" . urlencode($service);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // for debugging the request
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging the request

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); //for debugging the request
    //var_dump($response);

    curl_close($ch);

    if (strpos($response, '200 OK') === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // find the auth code
    preg_match("/(Auth=)([\w|-]+)/", $response, $matches);

    if (!$matches[2]) {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION['google_auth_id'] = $matches[2];
    return $matches[2];
}

function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) 
{
    $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
    $data = array(
                            'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
                            'collapse_key' => $msgType,
                            'data.message' => $messageText //TODO Add more params with just simple data instead           
                        );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
    if ($headers)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

**NOTE** : Feel free to contact in case of any doubts/query. Leave comment

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have some questions as i am new to this.Is there any framework required to implement this?And can i directly use your code into my webservice or should i have to make changes for that.

Comment: You can directly add your code but you need to do change in select query. You need to declare few constants in your configuration file. I appologize but this code is for PHP. Wait for while will give you solution for .net too for iOS push notification.

Comment: Check my other answer for .Net based code for Push Notification.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will try to implement your code and if there is any  query then will ask you.

Comment: hey as you have said i need to declare few constants in my configuration file.Is it required for .net webservice also?

Comment: Whats the APPLE_URL in this

Comment: @Akash it would be gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com for sandbox and gateway.push.apple.com for production.

Comment: k .. can u plz tell one thing device token remains same for all user for iphone app and if not how i get it dynimically ... and one more thing how i send notification for particular user with out user_id

Comment: This is server side code for push notification. If you have separate question please post it I will help to get it resolved.